# How do I delete a component from a managed package?

Tags: managed-package, delete, delete-managed-package

We created a managed package in our developer org and made it a released package. Afterwards, we decided to remove some custom fields from the managed package but saw no way of doing this in the org.

After looking at the documentation (e.g. [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=viewing_deleted_components.htm&type=5)), I discovered that I need to ask Salesforce to enable the feature for us to be able to remove components from a managed package.

Once this was done, I expected an option to remove the component from the managed package in package manager. This was not there, however, so it wasn't clear how to actually remove the component from the managed package. The documentation isn't really clear on this either.

Answer (score 0):

I turns out that I had to delete the field from the original object. Then, when viewing the package components in package manager, the custom fields were no longer there.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of things we need to keep in mind before deleting any managed component from the managed package. In your case when you need to delete the field you first need to remove all the references to the field, and then from the object setup, you can delete that field. If that too doesn't work for you, you need to ask salesforce to revert your package to a Beta package and then make the changes that you want in the package and release the new version of the package.

Here is one link for reference: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000312548&type=1

Hope this is helpful and adds up more knowledge in terms of deleting the managed components of a managed package.